# determining an effective and correct way to mathematical problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a task on hand and have been struggling to get the right number. Here is what I'm working with..

Part A
$63,569.60 <-- my goal to achieve (as close as possible, hopefully within cents).

Part B
277104

My goal is I need to update 277104 units, so that when multiple by a particular number/numbers it will equal the number in Part A. The problem I'm facing is that this is a $ dollar amount, so it cannot be longer than 2 decimal places: such as .23 or .24

Doing this =63569.6/277104   gives me a number .229 - now this creates lots of problems for me because I can't do 3 decimal places, but if I do .22 it is way short and .23 is a little more.

I am okay to multiple some units by .22 and some by .23 as long as they equal the number in Part A. Is there an easy way to calculate this??

Comment: Yes, suppose $n$ units are at $.22,$ and $277104-n$ units at $.23.$  Then you have one equation to solve for $n$.

Comment: This does not make sense whatsoever.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter why doesn't it make sense? I need a max 2 decimal number (.22) that when multiplied by 277104 will give me 63,596.60. There is no 2 decimal number that will give me the exact total. I am able to use 2 different 2 decimal numbers so when multiplied by the units 277104 will give me the exact number in Part A. I'd need to multiple a certain number of units by .22 and a certain number by .23. The gentleman below seemed to have understood the question and answered it correctly to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the number of units at $0.22$ dollars is $a$. Then, the number of units at $0.23$ dollars is $277104 - a$. Now, just set up a single variable equation.

$0.22a + 0.23(277104 - a) = 63569.60$

$0.22a - 0.23a + 63733.92  = 63569.60$

$-0.01a = -164.32$

$a = 16,432$

$277104 - 16432 = 260,672$

Therefore, you will need $16,432$ units at $22$ cents and $260,672$ units at $23$ cents.

Comment: Beautiful you sir are a genius. Thank you!